# How to display "hello world" in CQ5 using osgi

Tags: java, osgi, apache-felix, aem, sling

I need to learn how the code flows between sling and Felix in CQ5. I am looking for a basic operation in which my jcr node /jsp will display "Hello World". BUT this message should come from an OSGi bundle.

Basically, I need to create and install the bundle too. But at least I need to know the flow of control here.

Can someone please help on this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at this blog entry on dev.day.com entitled [Sling and OSGi](http://dev.day.com/content/ddc/blog/2008/05/slingosgi.html).  It describes creating a service, bundling it and calling it from a JSP.  It also says hello world!

Comment: @diffa... Again, you came to my rescue :) Thanks. (You sure gonna get lots of 'accept' rep. from me ;) )

Answer (score 2):

The http://sling.apache.org/documentation/getting-started/discover-sling-in-15-minutes.html tutorial should put you on the right track as well. I doesn't use OSGi components, for that you might want to look, as a next step at the Slingbucks sample at https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/sling/trunk/samples/slingbucks/

Answer (score 0):

You can also do the same thing from servlet too.This way you get a basic Idea of using Sling servlet with CQ as well.

you can call a sling sevlet bundled as OSGI bundle and deployed in CQ's system console. later you can  call, this OSGI bundle fire a post request and you will be able to get the response. here is a very nice and very explanatory tutorial that explain every and each steps.

http://scottsdigitalcommunity.blogspot.in/2013/06/posting-form-data-to-adobe-cq-using.html

and the sample code or sample application link can be found from here -

http://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/using/custom-sling-servlets.html

follow the above link step by step and you end up with the victory.